# Spark 2.3: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected

Tags: java, apache-spark

Recently updated the logic from `left_outer` join to `full` outer join and I started seeing this error:

```
ERROR util.ResourceLeakDetector: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
 Recent access records: 
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
 Exchange SinglePartition
 +- *(7) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#945L])
```

Found a similar old bug but I believe it should be fixed by now:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21181

Completely clueless on how to approach this problem.